# How to apply thermal paste for Dell Inspiron 3520 laptop?

Tags: cooling, dell-inspiron, thermal-paste, intel-core-i3

I am have a Dell Inspiron 3520 with a Intel Core i3-2730 CPU. CPU is rectangular in shape.

How should I apply thermal paste? I am already having Cooler Master Mastergel Pro. Can I use this thermal paste?

Comment: does the system use paste or a pad? You can't replace a thermal pad with thermal paste easily. Part of your question is a hardware/purchase recommendation, and is off topic. The rest of it isn't quite so I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to remove the heatsink, clean up the existing gunk by using a cottonswab dipped in iso-propyl alcohol and place a small pea drop at the centre of the processor.

Once the heatsink is mounted, the pressure of the mount should spread it evenly across the processor.

This is how much [I had applied](https://sathyabh.at/2017/05/23/mission-cooldown-reign-in-on-the-burning-hellforge-aka-how-i-cleaned-up-the-crud-off-my-cpu-heat-sinkfan/) for my i5-3470

[image]

Note that [CoolerMaster recommends](http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/thermal-compound/mastergel-maker/) spreading the gel across the CPU evenly with the spreader but in my experience that causes more problems and it's easier to just put a drop and let the heatsink do the job.

Comment: Its a laptop tho.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Also,what is the expiry date for Cooler Master Mastergel Pro?

Comment: Also CPU is rectangular in shape.So pea method works,right?